# fast answer from post request in rails + heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, tcp, dns

I'm creating my application using ruby on rails and deploy with heroku
in addition to the main page and several more, I have endpoints that are used by third-party applications to receive/record various information through a post request
with normal deployment + setup, I spend an additional 200 ms on DNS, TCP and SSL

Is it possible to make it so that specifically for these endpoints i can use http + static ip like domain to skip time for SSL and DNS?

I changed config.force_ssl to false and its give me skip SSL (save 80ms), but its work for all my request, I would like to limit ot only for endpoint roots

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that disabling SSL is a good idea. And I have worked with an application that had an average response time of under 10ms with SSL. Therefore, I doubt that SSL is the bottleneck.

But when you really want to try disabling SSL on certain routes only, then you can configure on what paths SSL should not be enforced.

`config.force_ssl = true` add the `ActionDispatch::SSL` to the application's middleware stack. The other configuration option (`ssl_options`) that can be used to fine-tune the behavior of the redirect.

In this example from the docs, with a health check route, that will not enforce SSL and will therefore not redirect to using SSL:

```
config.ssl_options = { 
  redirect: { exclude: -> request { /healthcheck/.match?(request.path) } } 
}
```

See docs for [`ActionDispatch::SSL`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/SSL.html).